# C++ Linker design question

Tags: c++, linux, linker, g++

So this is more a design question than anything, though any information about the g++ linker would be awesome.

I have .cpp files embedded in the following structure:

```
Main
Main/Utilities
Main/Utilities/Data
```

When I compile the main entry point .cpp in Main, I have to specify all the .cpp files any linked .cpp ever uses - this is working fine for my test project which only has like 5 linked files, but this project will grow very quickly and this is obviously infeasible. Is there a way to get around this? What is causing this?

I tried using "g++ *.cpp" but it wants me to link the others still. I have to do something like "g++ main.cpp Utilities/other.cpp Utilities/Data/data.cpp". other.cpp uses data.cpp, and main.cpp uses other.cpp. When compiling other.cpp I have to specify data.cpp like before.

Thank you very very much for any ideas or help!

Comment: I think you got some terminology confused. `g++` is the C++ compiler, not the linker. For your benefit, however, it will invoke the linker (on most UNIX systems that would be `ld`) in the background for you using the correct arguments.

Answer (score 3):

The general approach for managing a big project is to use a proper directory structure (like the one you already have in place) and then place a `Makefile` in each directory. The top level `Makefile` should recursively call the required `Makefiles`. Each `Makefile` should specify the source files that are to be compiled from that directory (and other compilation flags, if required). Ideally you should make static libraries (or maybe dynamic) depending on your requirement. Once you have all the dependent code compiled (means you have `.lib` or `.o` files with you), then you should compile the source file having the entry point (eg `main` function in c/c++) and specifying the dependent libraries to the linker (`ld`).

For an example, just look at any open source project that has at least 2 level directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

> ... I have to specify all the .cpp files any linked .cpp ever uses ...

This is false. You must give the linker enough information to resolve all the symbols used in the code, but you can do so as source code files (.cpp et al.), as object files (.o), or as libraries (.so or .a). It is sufficient to compile each of the source code files to object files, and then link each of the object files together in order to create the binary.

```
g++ foo.cpp -c -o foo.o
g++ bar.cpp -c -o bar.o
g++ main.cpp -c -o main.o
g++ main.o foo.o bar.o -o main.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are actually on a UNIX (like) system, so the shell will replace the `*.cpp` wildcard specification into actual filenames. Other systems may behave differently, though I doubt it.

You have stored your files in a directory structure, so simply saying `*.cpp` will only match the file in the current directory, where you invoke g++ - in your case presumably just main.cpp.

If you want to cover all the other files with wildcards as well, you'd have to specify them on the command line as well. In your case:

```
g++ *.cpp Utilities/*.cpp Utilities/data/*.cpp
```

If that is actually easier than simply naming all the files, I can't judge.

**EDIT:** as others have said, the best way to compile/build non-trivial programs is of course using `make` or some comparable build tool.